# How do I multiply all the elements in each row of a given matrix with corresponding elements of a given vector and sum them in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

For example, given a matrix `randn(3,2)` - 3 rows, 2 columns and a vector of multipliers `randn(1,2))` 2 columns, I want to get a vector of size `(3, 1)` in which each row would represent a sum of per element multiplication of the matrix's row elements and the given multipliers like

```
row_element_1*mul_element_1 + row_element_2*mul_element_2
```

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want a matrix-vector multiplication.

```
1> x = randn(3, 2)
x =

   0.62055  -1.08060
  -0.24064  -2.56097
  -0.53202  -0.49712

2> y = randn(1, 2)
y =

  -1.26010  -0.25200

3> x * y'
ans =

  -0.50964
   0.94860
   0.79567
```

Note the transposition `y'`.

Comment: That doesn't do what was requested.  There shouldn't be a transpose, and `y` should be 2x1 (as stated in the question).

Comment: @BenVoigt: seems to conform now. I don't see in the answer that "there shouldn't be a transpose".

Comment: Ah ok, the question did specify a 1x2 vector.  So your edit, removing the transpose on `x` and changing the size of and transposing `y`, is correct.  +1.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this with a combination of bsxfun and sum, like so:

```
a = rand(3,2);
b = rand(1,2);
result = sum(bsxfun(@times,a,b),2)

result =

   0.333379034494579
   0.613480382112731
   0.093702948350719
```

Note dimension argument to SUM to sum along each row (rather than the default, which is down columns). [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) applies a binary function with scalar expansion, which is ideal for the multiplication part here.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = randn(3, 2);
B = randn(1, 2);

C = A(:, 1) * B(1) + A(:, 2) * B(2);   % size(C) = [3, 1]
```

If you have to scale to a much larger array with lots more columns and didn't want to write out the equation for C in full, you can use [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) and element-wise multiplication

```
A = randn(300, 200);
B = randn(1, 200);

C = sum(A .* repmat(B, 300, 1), 2);
```